# Import RESX translation file trough PowerShell/PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, language

Took a lot of effort to translate each field from Dutch to French.
When I uploaded the resx file all was nicely translated.

Right now I would like to enable this translation on each site existing and newly created.

Trough PowerShell/PowerAutomate. Doesn't matter.
I uploaded the file already on

> tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/importtranslations.aspx

, no success.

any suggestions?